# windows switch user - how to prepopulate list of users?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a 2nd local user account on a windows 11 laptop.  To switch to that 2nd account I lock the screen ( windows key + L ), then click in lower left corner of screen. Which displays the current user and "other user".  How to prepopulate this list to include the name of the 2nd local user account?

( what I currently do is click on other user. Then at the login prompt I key in the qualified user name xxx\username.  Subsequent switching of user accounts then shows that user name in the list of users. )

Comment: This list populates with use and there is not (so far as I know) a native way to pre-populate the list. Just use the users.

Comment: Windows displaying a list of users that exist on the machine, is a group policy, if this is a corporate machine, then it's likely purposefully disabled. I suspect it is if you have to use the syntax `xxx\username` where `xxx` is the name of a domain. Furthermore the list typically only lists local accounts, again this behavior, is disabled by default typically.

Comment: To my knowledge, Windows Home versions have the full list, and windows Pro versions use the corporate version by default in windows 10. Not sure if they changed this in windows 11.

Comment: just my laptop at home.  The PC name is HPENVY11 and the user is steve.  I have to type in HPENVY11\steve.  Then next time I switch to user steve, steve is in the list of users and I only have to click on the name in the list.

Comment: Instead of using Win+L, can't you click in the Start menu on your name and select the other account by name?